# How to do OR of assertions in testing

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I have a API for user registration with a some fields you would expect from a regular user registration

The api returns response somewhat like this when registration is successful

```
{
    "response": {
        "httpCode": 200,
        "Message": "Registration is complete."
    }
}
```

But sometimes it might happen that email has already been taken , in that case a suitable message is returned with status code 400

```
{
    "response": {
        "httpCode": 400,
        "Message": "Email already taken."
    }
}
```

Now I am on testing it for which I've written this test case

```
public function testSignup()
{

    $response = $this->call('POST', '/api/signup', [

                            'first_name' => 'abc',
                            'last_name' => 'xyz',
                            'username' => 'iamgroot',
                            'email' => 'hello@example.com',

                ]);

    $response->assertStatus(200)->assertJsonStructure([

        'response' => [ 'httpCode' , 'Message' ]

    ]);

}
```

When giving a fresh email in testcase it passes(along-with other tests) but when run same test again it fails obviously since the response are different but speaking in a technical sense this isn't a failure really and code works as expected so how can I do something like OR so when either of two response formats is there it would pass since adding simply another assertion for status code 400 would just AND them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has a trait named DatabaseTransactions.

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class MyTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseTransactions;

    public function testSignup()
    {

        $response = $this->call('POST', '/api/signup', [
            'first_name' => 'abc',
            'last_name' => 'xyz',
            'username' => 'iamgroot',
            'email' => 'hello@example.com',
        ]);

        $response->assertStatus(200)->assertJsonStructure([
            'response' => [ 'httpCode' , 'Message' ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

This trait will use transactions, rollback the data after each test. You can, then, create an second test to force the error, something like this:

```
    public function testSignupError()
    {
        $email = 'test@example.com';
        //create an user to take the email
        factory(\App\User::class)->create(['email'=>$email]);

        $response = $this->call('POST', '/api/signup', [
            'first_name' => 'abc',
            'last_name' => 'xyz',
            'username' => 'iamgroot',
            'email' => $email,
        ]);

        $response->assertStatus(400);
    }
```

Or you can avoid the databasetransactions trait, and just create a new method, with a different email. Anyway, use `RefreshDatabase trait` to clean all data before the tests begun.

Comment: I've never used but `DatabaseTransactions` looks promising.But wouldn't 'pass' of these 2 tests would be mutually exclusive? ; if A pass B doesn't and vv.I only want to check that some server error/runtime error isn't there like so if status is either 200 or 400 (can ignore json structure for now) it should pass

Comment: No, because that is the expected behavior. If you want your server to give a 200 or 400 response, that's ok and the test should pass, if that is what you want.

Comment: Ohh...cool then I have just started on with testing and never used factories that's why got confused

Comment: I am onto implementing this so do I need to use `RefreshDatabase` as well?

Comment: Yes. RefreshDatabase is needed to clean you database before run the tests and make sure that you know what data is in

Answer (score 2):

Please try as follows:

```
$this->assertThat(
    $response->getStatusCode(),
    $this->logicalOr(
        $this->equalTo(200),
        $this->equalTo(400)
    )
);

$response->assertJsonStructure([
      'response' => [ 'httpCode' , 'Message' ]
]);
```

This will first assert that the response is either 200 or 400 and only then we will assert the JSON structure.

Comment: Thanks for your response , it gave me some ideas but `$response->assertStatus($response->getStatusCode())` would pass all status codes like 500,404 etc but I want to pass test only for 200 and 400